# Expand panel data python

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I am trying to expand the following data. I am a Stata user, and my problem can be fix by the command "fillin" in stata, now i am trying to rewrite this command in python and couldn't found any command that works.

For example: , transform this data frame:
(my dataframe is bigger than the example given, the example is just to illustrate what i want to do)

`id    year    X    Y 
  1    2008   10   20
  1    2010   15   25
  2    2011   2     4
  2    2012   3     6`

to this one

`id    year    X    Y 
  1    2008   10   20
  1    2009    .    .
  1    2010   15   20
  1    2011    .    .
  1    2012    .    .
  2    2008    .    .
  2    2009    .    .
  2    2010    .    .
  2    2011    2    4
  2    2012    3    6`

thank you, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using `.loc[]`

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2008,10,20],[1,2010,15,25],[2,2011,2,4],[2,2012,3,6]],columns=['id','year','X','Y'])
df = df.set_index(['id','year'])

# All combinations of index
#idx = list(product(df.index.levels[0], df.index.levels[1]))
idx = list(product(range(1,3), range(2008,2013)))

df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: This seems like a really elegant solution, but I am not able to make it work.  Is there a bug?  I get the following error: KeyError: '[(1, 2009), (1, 2011), (1, 2012), (2, 2008), (2, 2009), (2, 2010)] not in index'

Answer (score 1):

Create a new multi-index from the dataframe and then reindex

```
years = np.tile(np.arange(df.year.min(), df.year.max()+1,1) ,2)
ids = np.repeat(df.id.unique(), df.year.max()-df.year.min()+1)
arrays = [ids.tolist(), years.tolist()]
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), names=['id', 'year'])

df = df.set_index(['id', 'year'])

df.reindex(new_idx).reset_index()

    id  year    X       Y
0   1   2008    10.0    20.0
1   1   2009    NaN     NaN
2   1   2010    15.0    25.0
3   1   2011    NaN     NaN
4   1   2012    NaN     NaN
5   2   2008    NaN     NaN
6   2   2009    NaN     NaN
7   2   2010    NaN     NaN
8   2   2011    2.0     4.0
9   2   2012    3.0     6.0
```